# ¿Como poner lineas laterales entre TextView ? Android

Tags: android, login

Como puedo poner lineas laterales en un TextView algo así:

-- or --

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_sTfHHFt_Ok/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: no queda claro lo que necesitas

Comment: Sinceramente no veo que "lineas laterales" comentas =?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes definirlo en el layout

```
<!--TEXVIEW CON LINEAS -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TEXTO DEL TEXTVIEW"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#555"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tengo una duda. Al ser de tamaño 1dp, ¿habrá ocasiones en las que no se muestre la linea? dependiendo de los distintos tamaños y densidades de pantallas.

Comment: es el alto de la linea, siempre ocupara un pixel de alto, si la quieres más grande pues aumenta el numero a 2 o 3.  saludos